# Laravel collection reject not removing item

Tags: laravel, filter, collections

I have this

```
fulltreeCollection
0: 2
1: 10
2: 11
3: 12

subtree
0: 2
1: 3
2: 4
```

whatever exist in subtree but not exist in fulltreeCollection, i want to remove it.

so the end result of subtree should removed 3 and 4, left with
0: 2

```
$fulltreeCollection = collect($fulltreetest);
    $subtree = collect($subtreetest);

$filter2= null;

foreach($subtree as $subtreeuser){
        $exist = $fulltreeCollection->search($subtreeuser);

        if($exist==false){
            $removeuser= $subtreeuser;
            $filter2 = $subtree->reject(function ($value, $key) use($removeuser) {
                return $value ==$removeuser;
            });                   
        }
}
$filter2->all();
$newsubtree = $filter2;
```

but it end up some not remove. some problem ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're overthinking this:

```
$fulltreeCollection = collect($fulltreetest);
$newsubtree = collect($subtreetest)->filter(function ($value) use ($fulltreeCollection)  {
     return $fulltreeCollection->search($value) !== false;
});
```